# "near 100% pass rate"? or, "nearly 100% pass rate" - on a test?

Tags: grammar, phrases, descriptive-grammar

Which one is correct? The context is describing test results.

> 1. near 100% pass rate
> 2. nearly 100% pass rate

If they are both correct, is there any difference in meaning?

Also what are the reasons for using an adjective or adverb here?

Comment: We really need to see the whole sentence to answer this.

Comment: [R H K Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/near) gives the 'flat adverb' (traditional view) usage: '4. almost; nearly: a period of near 30 years.' That said, I'd prefer 'nearly' in their example. But when used as in your example, as in 'a near perfect performance', I'd say the flat form is much more idiomatic (and often hyphenated).

Comment: Maybe the choices should be 'a near 100% pass rate' or 'nearly a 100% pass rate'. Both forms look better with an 'a' added.

Comment: Both can be integrated into correct sentences the way @AlanGee demonstrates. Without context however, this is off-topic.

Comment: @AlanGee Or you can also have *a nearly 100% pass rate*, which is actually more frequent! (surprisingly perhaps).